# Stack that does Push, Pop and Median in O(1)

Tags: java, stack

Here are two implementation of a stack that does Push, Pop and Median in `O(1)`. Invite comments on complexity and betterment.

> Option - 1

```
public class MedianStack {

    private Deque<Integer> stack;
    private PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap;
    private PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap;

    public MedianStack(){
        stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
        maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    }
    public void push(int item){
        stack.offerFirst(item);
        minHeap.add(item);
        maxHeap.add(item);
    }
    public int pop(){
        int item = stack.poll();
        minHeap.remove(item);
        maxHeap.remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public int median(){
        return (minHeap.peek() + maxHeap.peek())/2;

    }
}
```

> Option - 2

**Modified and added after realizing the first implementation was not correct.**

```
public class MedianStack {

    private Deque<Integer> stack;
    private MedianHeap medianHeap;


    public MedianStack(){
        stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        medianHeap = new MedianHeap();

    }
    public void push(int item){
        stack.offerFirst(item);
        medianHeap.add(item);

    }
    public int pop(){
        int item = stack.poll();
        medianHeap.remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public int median(){
        return medianHeap.median();
    }
}
```

Median Heap Implementation

```
public class MedianHeap {

    private PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap;
    private PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap;

    public MedianHeap(){
        maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
    }

    public void add(int item){
        if(isEmpty()) minHeap.add(item);
        else{
            if(Integer.compare(item, median()) >= 0) minHeap.add(item);
            else maxHeap.add(item);
        }
        balance();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return maxHeap.size() == 0 && minHeap.size() == 0;
    }
    public void balance(){
        if(Math.abs(maxHeap.size() - minHeap.size()) > 1){
            if(minHeap.size() > maxHeap.size()){
                maxHeap.add(minHeap.poll());
            }else minHeap.add(maxHeap.poll());

        }
    }
    public void remove(int item){
        if(!minHeap.contains(item) || !maxHeap.contains(item)) throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal item removal");
        if(minHeap.contains(item)) minHeap.remove(item);
        else maxHeap.remove(item);
        balance();
    }

    public int median(){
        if (minHeap.size() == maxHeap.size()) return (maxHeap.peek() + minHeap.peek())/2;
        else if(minHeap.size() > maxHeap.size()) return minHeap.peek();
        else return maxHeap.peek();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>         minHeap.add(item);
>         maxHeap.add(item);
> ```

Adding to a `PriorityQueue` is not \$O(1)\$.  It is \$O(\log{n})\$.

Same thing for removal.

> ```
>     public int median(){
>         return (minHeap.peek() + maxHeap.peek())/2;
>
>     }
> ```

This is not a [median](https://www.mathsisfun.com/median.html).  The smallest and largest elements are totally irrelevant to a median.  In 4, 5, 6, then 5 is the median.  In -4000, 5, 6000, then 5 is still the median.  The only time you take an average to get a median is if there are an even number of elements in the set.  E.g. in 2, 4, 6, 8, then \$(4+6)/2 = 5\$ is the median.  Note that it is only the middle items in the set that matter.

Comment: Yup, I realise my implementation is wrong.

Comment: Updated post, added option 2 which is a correct implementation.

Comment: @Clockwork  Rather than [updating this post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/71574), you should [ask a new question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question) with the new code.  Note that the new code is not \$O(1)\$ for `push` and `pop` either.